# If I use a CSS grid layout on my webpage, and use fr will it look the same across all browsers?

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

So I learned about CSS grids today, and I had a question that I could not find an answer for. In my site I am creating, I used HTML tables as I did not yet know about css grids. Now that I have learned about them, I can see that grids are more useful and flexible in layout and style.

With the HTML tables, I can make it look perfect in a browser such as Google Chrome, but then I test it in FireFox and it slightly moves the divs around that I made.

If I used a grid system for a layout, and put all the content into that instead of using HTML tables, and then use the fr in css, would it keep the layout the same across web browsers? It would seem that way to me, since no matter what size of browser window or type of browser you are using, the fr keeps the grid to using 100% of the page size.

I apologize if what I am asking doesn't make too much sense. I tried to word it as best I could.

Comment: All major vendors support grid layout with the exception oft opera mini. Furthermore, IE11 dies only support an older spec. So in theory it should look the same across the board. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid Also: tables are not suited for layouting. Use tables for what they are made for: tabular data.

Comment: That makes sense. I also like that website you just linked to. Had no idea it existed but now should make all my questions like this easier to answer. For IE it shows it supports older with -ms-. What is the -ms- mean? I don't really know the number of people still using IE but I would like my site to reach the largest audience possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. It will look the same if the browser supports grid layout.
https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid

Comment: >What is the -ms- mean?
it's prefix for IE. There are several prefixes for compatibility with older browsers

-webkit-
-moz-
-ms-